# Sesiones en Larvel

Tags: laravel-5, session

Tengo el manejo de una tienda y cuando deseo ver el contenido del carro laravel me esta pidiendo que inicie sesion, la ruta no estaba protegida con dicha validación y no se que puede suceder, este es el controlador de la vista para dicha acción

```
public function Carro(){
      if (Session::has('carrito')) {
        $arreglo =Session::get('carrito');
        $total=0;
        foreach ($arreglo as $key => $value) {
          $total=$arreglo[$key]['attr12']+$total;
        }
        return view('cart',['total'=>$total]);
      }else{
        return view('cart');
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> Encontré el problema, tenia un llamado del `auth` en el controlador
>   del carrito

```
public function __construct()
  {
    $this->middleware('auth');
  }
```